# Windows docker "docker ps" is not working

Tags: docker

I'm new to docker.

Docker is started. But bellow error got.

> error during connect: Get
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.39/containers/json: open
>   //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
>   the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
>   run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
>   daemon is not running.

Comment: Are you sure you are running your command or PowerShell window as an elevated application? (Run as Administrator)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the similar issue and I fixed it using the following two commands in Windows PowerShell:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> cd "C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker"
PS C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker> ./DockerCli.exe -SwitchDaemon
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am experiencing the same error when i try to do 'docker ps' at an prompt with admin privileges, but when I executed the above two commands it didn't make the problem go away.